# Deleting selected feature on alt+click in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, features

Im trying to delete a feature on alt+click. The alt+click code works since i can print out the feature when i click on it. But, i thought i could simply remove it by using source.removeFeature(feature) but I cannot get it to work.

```
const selectAltClick = new Select({
  condition: function (mapBrowserEvent) {
    return click(mapBrowserEvent) && altKeyOnly(mapBrowserEvent);
  },
});

let select=selectAltClick;
map.addInteraction(select);

select.on('select', (e)=>{
  console.log(e.selected)
  vectorSource.removeFeature(e.selected);
})
```

My error:

```
Vector.js:1041 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 
'forEach')
at VectorSource2.removeFeatureInternal (Vector.js:1041:41)
at VectorSource2.removeFeature (Vector.js:1030:10)
at Select2.<anonymous> (main.js:256:16)
at Select2.Target2.dispatchEvent (Target.js:111:13)
at Select2.handleEvent (Select.js:537:12)
at Map2.PluggableMap2.handleMapBrowserEvent (PluggableMap.js:1073:34)
at MapBrowserEventHandler2.Target2.dispatchEvent (Target.js:111:13)
at MapBrowserEventHandler2.emulateClick_ (MapBrowserEventHandler.js:134:10)
at MapBrowserEventHandler2.handlePointerUp_ (MapBrowserEventHandler.js:210:12)
```

I´ve tried this as well
`vectorSource.removeFeature(e.selected[0])`

---

I found that my problem was that i had to remove my interactions for snapping and modifying before I can altclick on the feature to delete it. It now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the docs https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select.SelectEvent.html for select interaction `select` event, you'll see that `e.selected` is an array of all selected features, so in your case you need to refer to the first element of the array to remove selected feature:

```
vectorSource.removeFeature(e.selected[0]);
```

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/s9Lo6a8v/